# Is Large contiguous allocation on GPU global memory possible using smaller chunks?

Tags: cuda, malloc, gpu

I need to dynamically allocate a large portion of the GPU global memory, let's say 64 MB, which will take a lot of time; after allocation is completed a copy to/from the allocated space will start. I am wondering if it is possible to allocate that 64 MB in smaller chunks (for example 1 MB) and initiate an asynchronous copy on each of the allocated chunks? Please note that I want the final allocated space to be contiguous.

Another question, no asynchronous cudaMalloc or anything equivalent to that exist, right?

Comment: Thank you Greogr, my point was something else and I meant with respect to other instructions running on the GPU. But, this is a good point" memory allocation is typically O(n) in the number of pages". Does this also apply to cudaMalloc? Could you please provide a reference for that here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if it is possible to allocate that 64 MB in smaller chunks (for example 1 MB) and initiate an asynchronous copy on each of the allocated chunks? Please note that I want the final allocated space to be contiguous.

No it's not possible.  You have no control over where in the address space an allocation will be located.  There is no way to request an allocation located at a particular address, or that is adjacent to another allocation.  In this respect, the behavior and capability is quite similar to host `malloc` which also has none of these capabilities.

> Another question, no asynchronous cudaMalloc or anything equivalent to that exist, right?

There is no "async" version of `cudaMalloc`.  It will usually have blocking behavior because it is modifying the address map of the GPU.  This modification of the address map must occur when there is no other activity taking place on the GPU (i.e. no kernels executing, no copy operations underway).